# trying to copy files with extensions, shutil problems

Tags: python, shutil

When I run my code with shutil in #shutil.copyfile(dst, file), it prints everything out without error. I have issues using shutil

```
import os
import shutil

src = os.path.expanduser('~/Downloads')
print(src)
os.getcwd()
dst = os.getcwd
print(dst)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(('.txt', '.md')):
           print(os.path.join(root,file))
           #shutil.copyfile(dst, file)
```

EDIT:
I made the following changes to my code and it worked! Thank you everyone for your help

```
from os.path import join

dst = os.getcwd()

shutil.copyfile(join(src, file), join(dst, file))
```

Can anyone help me copy all the files, including the ones with same name (example 'readme' or other files that would be saved and have the same name)

Comment: Pls...add the error

Comment: `dst = os.getcwd` is wrong, it's assigning the **function** to `dst` not calling it.

Comment: try with this :    shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(root,file), dst )

Comment: @martineau thanks you for pointing it out!

Comment: MrClick: You're welcome. Is the problem solved?

Comment: yes! I made the changes but don't know how to put them in this comment section. Do you know how to add all the files, even if they had the same name? @martineau

Comment: Don't put them down here in the comments. If you wish, you can [edit] your question and put stuff in it. Personally, I think you should just delete your question, since the problem   was basically just caused by a typo…

Comment: @martineau it was actually the shutil.copyfile, plus the typo

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You never really said exactly what the `shutil` problem you're having is. Note that the files in `files` aren't full paths.

Comment: @martineau oh when I would run the original code without shutil (#) it printed out everything correctly. When i enabled the shutil, it never copied the files.